# How to center a map in Print Composer to the same center as in map window?

Tags: qgis, printing, layouts, print-composer

I can't figure out how can I **center the map in Print Composer to layer/object/map center** in the same way as in map window in **QGIS 1.8**. Let's say I have layer which I want have in the center of the map. In map window it is pretty easy - I just click on
"**Zoom to layer extent**".

Unfortunately when I create map frame in Map composer, the layer is
centered on width (good) but not centered on height (I guess it is aligned
to bottom).

If I use button *Set to map canvas extent* in *Print Composer / Item
Properties / Extents* it is again centered on width but this time aligned to
top.

I think in both cases it would be much better to have it centered. **Is there
any way to have map centered in Print Composer to the same center as map in
map window?**

Comment: Good call!  This would be a nice feature.  You could calculate the desired extent (though fiddling with the extent tends to change the map size in composer).  I find that the 'set to map canvas extent' tends to result in a rather more zoomed out view than I actually see in my map canvas, so I just use it to get close and then manually adjust as per Willy's answer.  Once I have it centered, I'll then adjust the scale to make it look like what I see on the map canvas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On my suggestion (Feature #6988) it was Fixed in changeset 5aac8bbfe060502944b4b4cc3bfb00860b583e98. So now after hitting **Set to map canvas extent**  in *Print Composer / Item Properties / Extents*  the map in map frame is centered both horizontally and vertically (at this moment only in weekly builds of QGIS 2.1 - I have tested it and it works)

Comment: Thank you for following up with this.  I'm at a loss as to why this is not the default.

Answer (score 13):

Well, With Qgis 2.0, you can click the "Layout" menu, then "Move Content", and adjust the layers to your liking

Comment: As with first answer, fiddling manually is not the way to properly center the map to object (polygon/layer) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

To do that I adjust the window of the map canvas. There is a control on the divider between the layer window to allow you to adjust width. By hand I guess the ratio to make it the same as the Print Composer.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that is not the way which works for me. I mean approximately manually set the ratio of map window is kind of very unsystematic and not precise. I guess in this case it is better to set zoom and pan (move item content) to desired extent directly in print composer. Anyway thanks again for giving it try :-)

Comment: Well if you are doing it more than once, you might be interested in using the Atlas tool and having a coverage layer to guide the extent. In that case I would refer you to other users as I am not familiar with the latest on Atlas which is in the trunk build.

Comment: Going to research Atlas tool, thank you. I have also added this as issue to hub.qgis.org to get map centered on height when adding map frame and using button Set to map canvas extent.